# Python Search and Replace new lines

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting translate multiline records from the following to a single line records.

Before =>

```
Item ID:
504246
Teddy Ruxpin, 
Stuffed Animal, Bear
Item Price:
$34.50
Status:
Discontinued
Ages:
4-9
Qty:
895

Item ID:
783927
Monopoly, 
Board Game
Item Price:
$29.67
Status:
Active
Ages:
8+
Qty:
190200
```

After =>

```
Item ID: 504246, Teddy Ruxpin, Stuffed Animal, Bear, Item Price: $34.50, Status: Discontinued, Ages: 4-9, Qty: 895

Item ID:, 783927, Monopoly, Board Game, Item Price: $29.67, Status: Active, Ages: 8+, Qty: 190200
```

However, whenever I look up different Python libraries I only find examples of replacing words, not new lines.

Comment: Please specify which one is before and which one is after what you expect. Also, provide the attempts you have made. Is it a csv file? Is there a delimiter?

Comment: You want to store it in a single list of dictionaries?

Comment: Can one assume that the items are normalised? In the input various delimiters are used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
import re

datastring = """Item ID:
504246
Teddy Ruxpin, 
Stuffed Animal, Bear
Item Price:
$34.50
Status:
Discontinued
Ages:
4-9
Qty:
895

Item ID:
783927
Monopoly, 
Board Game
Item Price:
$29.67
Status:
Active
Ages:
8+
Qty:
190200
"""

separator=";"
for line in datastring.split("Item ID:"):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    line = "Item ID: %s" % line
    line = re.sub(r":\w*\n",": ",line,re.M)
    line = re.sub(r"\n","%s "%separator,line,re.M)
    print line
```

First we need to split the records using "Item ID:". Strip each line of leading and trailing whitespace and then skip empty lines. For the remaining lines we prepend "Item ID:" because it was removed by split. Then we execute 2 regex substitutes:

1. Substitute new line character with ": " from places containing a "label" ie. ending with colon, possible white space and a new line character.
2. substitute all remaining new line characters with selected separator character (I used semicolon in the code).

As a last step in the for loop, I print the line. Output is something like this:

```
Item ID: 504246; Teddy Ruxpin, ; Stuffed Animal, Bear; Item Price: $34.50; Status: Discontinued; Ages: 4-9; Qty: 895
Item ID: 783927; Monopoly, ; Board Game; Item Price: $29.67; Status: Active; Ages: 8+; Qty: 190200
```